My audience has a lower version of android but Google Play console requires API 33 now
Your app currently targets API level 31 and must target at least API level 33 to ensure it is built on the latest APIs optimized for security and performance\
My audience has a lower version of android but Google Play console requires API 33 now. Can someone help me how to solve this problem
I've tried to upload the lower version but of course it ist not valid in the google play console.
and my users tried to install the latest version SDK 33 but they cannot install them in Google Play. :(

there are two things ,minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion. Increase the Target and keep the minSDK version to as low as you can support.
